# accessing dict in django template

Tags: python, django, psql

I have a django project writing to a PSQL database and I am figuring out how to check which queries are being done.

Is there a way to check which queries actually make it to the database? I noticed some queries are cached and use no actual call to the database.
 (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets)

Reason why I ask:

I have a model `JobId`, which holds all jobs processed on my platform. Processing jobs uses credits. At the end of each job, I save the `JobId.credit_detla` (= amount credits used) and `JobId.credits` (= amount credits on account left).

I want to show the `JobId.credits` in the navigation menu but don't want to pull queries on every visited page for this single value.

So 2 questions:

- how could I figure out the quantity of queries?
- is there a better typical-one-liner-code practice to get this query result in my navigion menu?

Answer (score 0):

The [Django debug toolbar](https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar) is exceptional for these kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

Django allows you to log all database queries; checkout the Django doc [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/logging/#django-db-backends).

Regarding showing remaining credits: if it's sufficient to only update the number once per session, then I would fetch it on login and store it in the user session. You can then retrieve it without a DB query from the session.

It's a bit trickier if you want it to update. In that case, you would need to create a small service (view) that you could periodically query via javascript and update live on the page.